# Reboot into second OS, retain state

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot

I have a dual boot system using Ubuntu and Windows 10. I regularly have to reboot into Windows so my son can play VR/other games. Yes, my son.

Is there a way to retain the state of my Ubuntu OS before rebooting so I can reboot into Windows and back without losing my workspace?

For bonus points, I'd love to retain the state of BOTH OS when rebooting :)

I suspect the answer is: not possible, but who knows?

Comment: try hibernation

Comment: No, not possible. @arielnmz Using hibernation the computers boots the hibernated OS, not Grub.

Comment: This is what I thought. Why the down votes on the question?

Comment: It's perfectly possible. You will need to configure hibernation on each OS. Then you can hibernate one OS and on restart boot into the other (which will restore its hibernated state). You may need to go into the BIOS boot menu to do this. The limitation is that you cannot access the partitions mounted to a hibernated OS when you boot the other.

Comment: I would echo the concern about enforcing isolation between the systems in this case. A hibernated version of Windows would retain a lot of filesystem state information for its mounted partitions and is not particularly friendly about it changing while it is hibernated and can cause instability and corruption. Having no "common" filesystems between the two should mean that it works okay.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I do have a shared drive, sadly, which has the gaming stuff on it. Perhaps I can rework that and try it.

Comment: Provided that you dismount the shared drive from Linux before you hibernate it will be mountable in Windows; and vice versa.

Comment: Perhaps add a virtual instance? BTW, my experience is that Windows can hibernate and restart successfully, but *only* if I've not tried to boot into Linux in between. It theoretically *should* be possible, though, if the two OS's are on separate partitions and never mounted simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

probably too late but I stumbled on this while I was looking for a solution to this problem so I thought I would answer this question for anyone else facing the same problem. This guide does a great job walking you through the process
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150556)